# Verilog: sampling data in both posedge and negedge of the clock

Tags: verilog, clock

I have a serial input stream which has left data in posedge of the clock, and right data in negedge of the clock.

I would like to synchronize and bring them to the posedge of the same clock.

I could do that using another clock with twice of the frequency.

How to synchronize the data using the same clock?

Answer (score 1):

Use the negedge of the clock to sample the "right" data and store it to a register, then use  the posedge to sample the "left" data and the register.

```
reg r;
always @(negedge clock) begin
    r <= right_data;
end

always @(posedge clock) begin
    // use left_data and r here
end
```